# Bulk convert test cases to coded-ui

Tags: testing, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I have some 50+ recorded test cases in Microsoft Test Manager that I have to import as coded-ui in visual studio 2010.

Right now for each one I create a new coded-ui test -> Use existing action recording -> find the test case -> rename the file to the test case name -> link the test case with the coded-ui.

It is a very repetitive and time consuming process so is there a way to automatically do this for all the 50+ tests?

Comment: I know this is perhaps a bit silly, but could you write a coded UI test that automates it in a loop? ;)